# HQ camera locks when using python library

Tags: camera, picamera

The new HQ camera module is amazing and works really well using `raspistill` for long exposures. Using the `picamera` python library the camera locks with exposures above 10s (the maximum for the V2 camera). This is my code, am I doing something wrong or is the library not compatible?

```py
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.iso = 800
camera.sensor_mode=3
camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
camera.framerate=Fraction(1, 20)
camera.shutter_speed = 20000000
camera.iso = 800
camera.start_preview()
# Give the camera some time to adjust to conditions
time.sleep(20)
camera.capture('test.jpg')
```

Comment: Try `sudo SKIP_KERNEL=1 rpi-update; sudo reboot` that will get new firmware for the HQ camera.

Comment: Thanks. I now get `Timed out waiting for capture to end`

Comment: Go and read the Raspberry Pi forum https://raspberrypi.org/forums

Comment: I've been looking there and had drawn a blank. This thread looked promising but didn't fix my issue - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=276556